Occurs error "ClassNotFoundException: net.minidev.json.JSONObject" with the minidev relocated dependency
An error occurs when i trying to add the spring-security-oauth2-client dependency.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minidev.json.JSONObject
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.lambda$oidc$0(ClientRegistrations.java:164) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
...

I thought that when I add a dependency with JSONObject, the problem would go away.
I added net.minidev:json-smart to the project, but the problem has not disappeared
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'net.minidev:json-smart:2.5.1'
    ...
}

I started to figure out why net.minidev.json.JSONObject does not appear in classPath.
The project also has other dependencies. There is an assumption that the source of the problem is the bom org.camunda.bpm:camunda-bom.
api(enforcedPlatform('org.camunda.bpm:camunda-bom:7.20.0'))

I noticed that the relocations construction is used inside this bom (https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/3f6cb3055232c0fa9958e7a351af6ea0eafd7bb2/spin/dataformat-all/pom.xml#L79):
part from camunda-bpm-platform pom-file with net.minidev relocation:
...
<relocations>
    ...
    <relocation>
      <pattern>net.minidev</pattern>
      <shadedPattern>spinjar.com.minidev</shadedPattern>
    </relocation>
    ...
</relocations>
...

Indeed, JSONObject can be called using the path spinner.com.minidev.json.JSONObject'.
How can I return this relocation? So that spinner.com.minidev.json.JSONObject becomes net.minidev.json.JSONObject again ?
I looked for shadow plugins for gradle. But dont understand what to do. Maybe there is a simple solution?
